MarginNotes in LyX: can we redefine \marginar as \todo from todonotes package?
LyX offers a way to redefine the command used by LyX for margin notes by the command provided by the marginnote-package (See Help > Embedded Objects > 4.3 Margin Notes ), by adding these two lines to the document preamble:
\usepackage{marginnote}
\let\marginpar\marginnote

However, this does NOT work for the todonotes-package:
\usepackage{todonotes}
\let\marginpar\todo

After adding above two lines in the document preamble, I get an error when use the Margin Note box. I think this is because the todonotes-package also use \marginar as it's fundamental command, which may cause nesting problem. Is there any way that replace \marginpar to \todo only once, so that everything works?
Example: the following *.tex code works, however it fails when uncomment \let\marginpar\todo
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{todonotes}
%\let\marginpar\todo

\begin{document}
AAAAAA \marginpar{A small Test} CCC
\hrulefill

\vspace{3cm}
BBBBBB \todo{A small Test} CCC
\hrulefill
\end{document}


why do you want to use the longer generic command \marginpar  instead of the shorter and semantic command \todo??

@UlrikeFischer  LyX is kind of a WYSIWYG editor. It can create a Margin Note box in editor by just a click. However, this box is based on the command  \marginpar; if I still want to use this click box, I need to "cheat" it  by  let \marginpar to  be \todo. This also the Help document of LyX mentioned to use marginnote-package, as I shown above.

I would suggest not to cheat but to ask the lyx maintainer to add an option to add a todo.

@UlrikeFischer Thanks for your suggestion. But there are many choices. For example, we may also use sidenotes-package. It's impossible to create boxes for each one. Seems that there are sth. like \expandafter ,\csname..\endcsname, e.t.c. can do what I want. But I don't know how to do that.

lyx could add some option to let you choose for which command the note box should create a command. Sorry but I do not think that it is a good idea to remap marginpar onto todo and I won't spent my time on it. You can not control the side effects. As you mention sidenotes: it uses \marginpar too and you don't know how it will react if that is suddently a todo.

You can use the same approach that showed here to use the LyX comments (from verbatim) for the pdfcomment package:
That is, in the preamble:
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{environ}
\RenewEnviron{comment}{\todo{\BODY}}

And then,  in the text use Insert → Note  → Comment  → insert your margin note →  Ctrl+R → voilá.
Edit
In the latest LyX version (2.4.1) you can also use directly the package using the TODO Notes module:
Document →
Settings... →
Modules →
Annotation & Revision →
TODO Notes →
Add →
OK
And then insert a margin note with:
Insert → Custom Inset  → TODO Note (Margin)
Customization of the package can be done via document class options, and options for particular \todo note can be done with the contextual menu:

(And yes, the orange background is horrible.)

Very useful. Thanks! One more comment, DON'T USE \renewcommand{\marginpar}[1]{...} to set fontsize of the marginNotes, it will cause a wrong presentation. Instead, directly set on \BODY. For example,\RenewEnviron{comment}{\todo[linecolor=blue,backgroundcolor=blue!25,bordercolor=blue]{\scriptsize\hspace{0pt}\emph{\BODY}\par}}

@XLeo Better set the font size with the textsize package option or  the size option in the \todo command.  BTW, the \hspace and the  \par seems superfluous here. E.g.:   \usepackage[textsize=scriptsize]{todonotes}\usepackage{environ} \RenewEnviron{comment}{\todo[fancyline]{\em\BODY}}
